# How can I use function to place inputs on this code? I have no clue because I am a beginner

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

I need help placing inputs when the user define the Name and ID, Salary, Activity, Background and Payment Way, I already process this code and everything works properly, all I need is the inputs but I am having some troubles trough the logic of this process, I am just a beginner. Thanks in advance.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>INSURANCE</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var d=document,
            nameId=prompt('Enter Name and ID'),
            salary=prompt('Enter Salary'),
            activity=Number(prompt('\nDedicated: \n1.Administration and education \n2.Industry \n3.Transportation\n4.Construction')),
            background=Number(prompt('\nBackground: \n1.0-3 \n2.4-10 \n3.10+')),
            tipoPago=Number(prompt('\nPayment way: \n1.Monthly \n2.Quarterly \n3.Biannual \n4.Anual')),
            totalhis = 0, totalPay=0, total=0, prime=0; //NOTICE!!! 4 vars single line.
                //switch for activity
            var admiNedu=salary*0.03,
                industry=salary*0.06,
                transport=salary*0.10,
                construction=salary*0.15;

            switch (activity){
                case 1: prime=admiNedu;
                        break;
                case 2: prime=industry;
                        break;
                case 3: prime=transport;
                        break;
                case 4: prime=construction;
                        break;
                    }
                    //switch for background
            var months3=0,
                months4to10=prime*0.02,
                plus10=prime*0.05;

            switch (background){
                case 1: totalhis=0;
                        break;
                case 2: totalhis=months4to10;
                        break;
                case 3: totalhis=plus10;
                        break;
                    }
                    //switch for tipoPago
            var monthlyPay=prime*0.06,
                trimestPay=prime*0.05,
                semestPay=prime*0.04,
                anualPay=0;

            switch (tipoPago){
                case 1: totalPay=monthlyPay;
                    break;
                case 2: totalPay=trimestPay;
                    break;
                case 3: totalPay=semestPay;
                    break;
                case 4: totalPay=anualPay;
                    break;
            }
            total=prime+totalhis+totalPay;
            d.writeln('Name and ID ' + nameId)
            d.writeln('Salary ' + salary)
            d.writeln(total)
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by placing iputs?

Comment: @MatúšDúbrava when you enter information on input='text' id='bla bla bla' I don't know how to make it works. What I need is the inputs to fill out a form with the information requested by the program. So instead of placing prompts which is horrible, you place blanks so the user just have to enter the information without watching the prompts.

Comment: I still do not partially understand. Are you asking how to get value (typed by user) from input box?

Comment: @MatúšDúbrava look a this example and sorry about my english but I am not a native speaker
`<body><button type='button' onclick='inicio()'>Try it</button>
<input type='text' id='texto' value='hola'></input>
    <script>
 function inicio(){
 var resultado=suma(12,3,4);
   document.getElementById('texto').setAttribute('value', resultado);}

  function suma(n1,n2,n3){
   var total=n1+n2+n3;
   return total;
  }

  </script>
 </body>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the value of input text field like this (using jquery):

```
var value = "something"; // value to be displayed

$("#text-input").val(value);  // where text-input is id of the input field
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CBSeZ/4/

And with plain javascript:

```
var value = "something";

var elem = document.getElementById("text-input");
elem.value = value;
```